# Как получить значение поля из формы в шаблоне django?

Tags: django

Как получить данные из поля формы шаблона? Форма задается в явном виде. Мне нужно получить два значения: increment и decrement, а потом обработать из в представлении. Приведу код.

шаблон

```
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_modificate' product.id %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{cart.product}}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="increment" value="increment" />
   <input type="submit" value="+" />
</form>
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_modificate' product.id %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{cart.product}}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="decrement" value="decrement" />
   <input type="submit" value="-" />
</form>
```

начало представления

```
def cart_modificate(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    increment =
```

Можно, конечно создать два представления для каждой формы. Но мне хочется обойтись одним.

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть что находится в `request.POST`

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Все получилось.

шаблон:

```
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_modificate' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{product.id}}" />
     <input class="cart_form" name="button" type="submit" value="+" />
     <input class="cart_form" name="button" type="submit" value="-" />
</form>
```

представление:

```
def cart_modificate(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST['id']
        button = request.POST['button']
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        if button == '+':
            increment = button
            decrement = None
        else:
            increment = None
            decrement = button
        cart.modificate(product, increment, decrement)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```